# Displaying binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
    deriving (Show)
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to display a binary tree in a manner such that for each level I go down in the tree, I want to add an additional `*` next to the name of the node and have them all separated by `\n`.

For example:

```
let x = Node "Parent" (Node "childLeft" (Node "grandChildLeftLeft" Emp Emp) Emp) (Node "childRight" Emp Emp)
putStrLn $ displayTree x
```

should return:

```
"Parent"
*"childLeft"
**"grandChildLeftLeft"
*"childRight"
```

My function (only prints up to one `*`):

```
displayTree :: Show a => BinTree a -> String
displayTree Emp = ""
displayTree (Node head Emp Emp) = (show head)
displayTree (Node head left Emp) = (show head) ++ "\n*" ++ displayTree left
displayTree (Node head Emp right) = (show head) ++ "\n*" ++ displayTree right
displayTree (Node head left right) = (show head) ++ "\n*" ++ displayTree left ++ "\n*" ++ displayTree right
```

My `displayTree` function would print:

```
"Parent"
*"childLeft"
*"grandChildLeftLeft"
*"childRight"
```

I want `"grandChildLeftLeft"` to have `**` next to it instead of just `*`.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: I don't want to change the parameters that are passed into the function, so it should stay as `displayTree :: Show a => BinTree a -> String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
module Main (main) where

data BinTree a = Empty | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
    deriving (Show)

showTree :: Show a => BinTree a -> Int -> String
showTree (Empty) _ = []
showTree (Node t l r) n = replicate n '*' ++ show t ++ "\n" ++ showTree l (n+1) ++ showTree r (n+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let x = Node "Parent" (Node "childLeft" (Node "grandChildLeftLeft" Empty Empty) Empty) (Node "childRight" Empty Empty)
    putStrLn $ showTree x 0
```

Note the accumulator `n` which changes the indent level with each recursive call.

---

http://ideone.com/lphCoV

```
"Parent"
*"childLeft"
**"grandChildLeftLeft"
*"childRight"
```

Comment: Ah, better use of Haskell than my answer, but two minor typos :). I'm pretty sure the end of your function should be `showTree r (n+1)` instead of `showTree l (n+2)`

Comment: Oops, had it in my head as a regular tree.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier but I wanted to do this in a way that I would not have to change the parameters my display function would take.

Comment: You can copy `showTree` and move it into a `where` which you call with `0` so the original function still has the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass in the depth to the displayTree function?

```
displayTree :: Show a => BinTree a -> String 
displayTree = displayTree' ""

displayTree' str Emp = ""
displayTree' str (Node head Emp Emp) = str ++ (show head)
displayTree' str (Node head left Emp) = str ++ (show head) ++ "\n" ++ displayTree' (str ++ "*") left
displayTree' str (Node head Emp right) = str ++ (show head) ++ "\n" ++ displayTree' (str ++ "*") right
displayTree' str (Node head left right) = str ++ (show head) ++ "\n" ++ displayTree' (str ++ "*") left ++ "\n" ++ displayTree (str ++ "*") right
```

Also, here's it refactored to be kinda more readable:

```
displayTree :: Show a => BinTree a -> String 
displayTree = displayTree' ""

displayTree' str Empty = ""
displayTree' str (Node h l r) = hstr ++ lstr ++ rstr
    where
        hstr = str ++ (show head) ++ "\n"
        lstr = makeTreeStr l
        rstr = makeTreeStr r
        makeTreeStr Empty = ""
        makeTreeStr tree = displayTree' (str ++ "*") tree ++ "\n"
```